# Placing several divs on a div and changing the size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fiddle of my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/grqdpeyh/

```
.scoreboard{
margin-left: 70%;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 1%;
}

.sc_place{
    height: 42px;
}
```

There are five div's with class *sc_place*, which I need them to be in between track lines. The background div (track) resizes automatically on windows resize.
I managed to make the horses resize with the track, but can't do the same with the *sc_place* divs.

By the way I'm using a bootstrap for my main website, if that helps anything.

--EDIT--

This is the full code of my middle area:

```
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <!-- PROGRESS -->

                <div class="progress text-center" style="height:30px">
                    <span id = "pbanner"></span>
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" id="timebar" style="width:100%"></div>
                </div>

                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/track/top.jpg"></img>
                <!--<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/track/main.jpg"></img>-->
                <div class="maintrack">
                    <div class="horse" style="margin-top: -8%;"></div>
                    <div class="horse" style="margin-top: -4%;"></div>
                    <div class="horse" style="margin-top: 0%;"></div>
                    <div class="horse" style="margin-top: 5%;"></div>
                    <div class="horse" style="margin-top: 9%;"></div>

                    <div class="scoreboard">
                        <div class="sc_place text-center">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="sc_place text-center">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="sc_place text-center">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="sc_place text-center">TEXT</div>
                        <div class="sc_place text-center">TEXT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grqdpeyh/8/

But I don't think it really matters though.

Comment: Can you update fiddle too ?

Comment: This should work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/arpit_goyal/x0gtqa8y/

Comment: @ArpitGoyal this indeed worked, just needed to edit the font size a little, it's still a little off but I can bare with that, thanks a lot! I will accept your reply as an answer.

Comment: line-height works ? doesn't it ? https://jsfiddle.net/grqdpeyh/9/

Comment: @GCyrillus yes it works aswell, I will also vote up your answer.

Comment: @NedasMikoleika Happy to help :)

Comment: thanks for the feed back, have fun with your site ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS for `.sc_place`:

```
.sc_place{
  height:5vw;
  font-size:3vw;
}
//in case of image in place of font this can be replace with font-size
background: url(http://buruburu.gr/wp-content/uploads/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_others/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_others_01.jpg) no-repeat contain;
```

Or check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/arpit_goyal/x0gtqa8y/

Comment: @NedasMikoleika https://jsfiddle.net/arpit_goyal/sj4k8765/ check this, works for me

Comment: @NedasMikoleika this works, you got the idea here , just tune the vw value to your wishes. then mediaquerie can be used to avoid font-size to groww too ... small to be read

Comment: But the div's themselves are in wrong place, as you can see here in my website: http://puu.sh/nuuEl/abcb601e09.jpg

Comment: @NedasMikoleika is it that your test case doesn't reflect your real case ? are these divs holding image ? ... can you update your question :)

Comment: @ArpitGoyal not sure it is a good idea to edit your answer with same answer of mine, both ideas where worthit :)

Comment: @NedasMikoleika you can have a mush simpler solution if you have images in there, just update your fiddle Then I can do it

Comment: @GCyrillus I though that's what you suggested me, never mind reverted back to original :)

Answer (score 2):

you can set line-height with vw values:

```
sc_place{
    line-height:4.65vw
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/grqdpeyh/1/

edit: line-height works as i can see ? https://jsfiddle.net/grqdpeyh/9/